# Property of 2-natural transformations

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, natural-transformations, 2-categories

Let $C$ and $D$ be (strict) 2-categories, let $F,G:C\to D$ be (strict) 2-functors, and let $\alpha:F\Rightarrow G$ be a (strict) 2-natural transformation.

Let now $X$ and $Y$ be objects of $C$, let $f,g:X\to Y$ be parallel 1-morphisms of $C$, and $\beta:f\Rightarrow g$ be a 2-morphism of $C$.

Consider the components $\alpha_X:FX\to GX$ and $\alpha_Y:FY\to GY$ of $\alpha$, these are arrows of $D$. Consider also the 2-morphisms $F\beta:Ff\Rightarrow Fg$ and $G\beta:Gf\Rightarrow Gg$, which are 2-morphisms of $D$.

Denoting the [whiskering](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/whiskering) just by juxtaposition, is it true that $\alpha_Y\, (F\beta) = (G\beta) \,\alpha_X$?

(A way to interpret this property, if true, is "naturality condition on 2-cells".) Anyway, does this hold?

A reference would also be welcome.

Comment: This is part of the definition of a 2-natural transformation. Do you have a reference for the definition you're trying to extract this condition from?

Comment: One I could use is Tom Leinster's "Basic bicategories", arXiv:math/9810017

Answer (score 1):

The property is true. It can be found for example in ["2-dimensional categories" by Johnson and Yau](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06055), explanation 4.2.4 in section 4.2, where they consider the lax natural case. For strict natural transformations, their 2-cells $\alpha_f$ are identities.

The condition asked in the OP corresponds indeed to naturality of the 2-cell $\alpha_f$ in $f$.